# Stop WordPress fetch_feed from stripping anchor tags

Tags: wordpress, twitter, rss, simplepie

I am using the WordPress `fetch_feed` function to pull in some Tweets. All works nicely but all html tags are stripped from the content. I would like to stop anchor tags from being stripped but just can't quite nail it.

```
<?php
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$rss = fetch_feed('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=Your_LEAP_Lewes&rpp=3');
if( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) {
    //max items is actually set in the twitter url un this case.
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(3);
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
}
?>

<div class="twitter-feed">
    <div class="twitter-header clearfix">
        <h2>Our latest Tweets</h2>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/Your_LEAP_Lewes" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @Your_LEAP_Lewes</a>
        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
    </div>
    <ul class="twitter-ul clearfix">
        <?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>No items.</li>';
        else

        // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink.
        foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
        <?php 
        //print_r($item); 

        ?>

        <li>
        <?php echo $item->get_description(); ?>
        <span class="tweet-date"><?php echo $item->get_date('j M'); ?></span>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, I think your syntax may be wrong in your if/else code, plus it's really hard to read.

```
<?php
   if ($maxitems == 0) {
      echo '<li>No items.</li>';
   } else {
        // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink.
        foreach ( $rss_items as $item )
        {
           echo '
        <li>'.$item->get_description().'
           <span class="tweet-date">'.$item->get_date('j M').'</span>
        </li>';
        }
   }
?>
```

I think because your else statement wasn't bracketed properly that it only executed the next line, which is a comment. I might be wrong, but this is still easier to read.

As far as stripping HTML tags, check out the [strip_htmltags()](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/strip_htmltags) function. If the WordPress implementation sets this, you may be able to override it in your code.